# n log n is O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I am trying to solve this recurrence

T(n) = 3 T(n/2) + n lg n ..

I have come to the solution that it belongs to masters theorem case 2 since n lg n  is O(n^2)

but after referring to the solution manual i noticed this solution that they have

[image]

The soluttion  says that n lg n = O ( n ^(lg 3 - e)) for e between 0 and 0.58

so this means n lg n is O(n) .. is this right? Am i missing something here?

Isn't nlgn O(n^2) ?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This will explain things better
[image]

Comment: thanks for the effort .. So I guess n lg n > O(n) .. and the book is wrong?

Comment: @WaelAwada The book's answer does not contradict O(n log n) > O(n).

Comment: @WaelAwada The excerpt from the book looks a written form (if unfortunate for swapping first and second term) for: _We_ have two terms to consider for stating simple dominating functions: _n lg n_ and _n^logb a_. Since _n lg n_ is dominated by _n to the power of **anything** larger than one_, it is dominated by _n^lg 3_.

Comment: Did you take that chart from here? http://bigocheatsheet.com You should credit your source!

Comment: That chart's purple line for O(nlogn) is wrong. Look at 100 on the x-axis. It should map to 100*log(100) = 100*2 = 200. Instead it maps to approximately 650 in the chart. Maybe they're throwing in a constant multiplier, but they didn't do it for the other lines. Weird.

Comment: It is Log2(100) ~ 7

Answer (score 15):

`n*log(n)` is not `O(n^2)`. It's known as quasi-linear and it grows much slower than `O(n^2)`. In fact `n*log(n)` is less than polynomial.

In other words:

```
O(n*log(n)) < O(n^k)
```

where `k > 1`

In your example:

```
3*T(2n) -> O(n^1.585)
```

Since `O(n^1.585)` is polynomial and dominates `O(n*log(n))`, the latter term drops off so the final complexity is just `O(n^1.585)`.

Comment: I thought the latter term only drops when it is addition .. so O(n + lg n) = O(n)

Comment: It also drops off in this case too. But it'll take an all-out example/analysis to show why.

Answer (score 6):

n<sup>lg3</sup> is not O(n).  It outgrows O(n)... In fact, any exponent on n that is larger than 1 results in an asymptotically longer time than O(n).  Since lg(3) is about 1.58, as long as you subtract less than .58 from the exponent it is asymptotically greater than O(n).

Comment: So if i understand correctly, you, like me, are thinking the solution manual is wrong by saying n lgn = O(n)

Comment: No!  n log n is bigger, outgrows, and is NOT bounded by n.  It's the other way around.

Comment: f(n) = O(g(n)) if f(n) < c.g(n) for for all n > n0 .. so if n lg n = O(n) what would c and n0 be ?

Comment: Let c = 1 and n0 be 5, and you'll see that it's NOT TRUE.  The other way around is.

Comment: so if the other way around is then n = O(n lg n) which I understand but the book is saying n lgn = O (n)